# Difference between font sizes on mobile vs desktop browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I havet tried reading about making font sizes responsive and about using device-width for mobile browsers. But I just cant seem to make sense of it. The font size in proportion to the window is a lot different between mobile and desktop browsers. How can I solve this?

This is my current css for my h1:

```
h1 {
font-size: 3em;
}

@media (min-width: 520px) {

h1 {
    font-size: 3.5em;
}
}

@media (min-width: 760px) {
h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
}
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
h1 {
    font-size: 5em;
}
}
```

And yes, I have included this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Please DO NOT link to your wbsite. Here's why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: You shouldn't set the font-size on mobile. People can set their own. Use that. Then use em and rem to give boxes a size.

Answer (score 1):

There are varying ways to solve this.  When I can get away with it (simple layout, content-driven site) I leave `1em` alone, letting the device figure out what size the text should be for it.  Everything is scaled from there.

Since `em`s are relative measurements, you shouldn't be setting the size of your headings differently for every width of device.  Set your heading at `2em` or wherever you want it, and then let it scale from the base font size on `body`.  Then, if you have to do any scaling at all, just set that base font size and the rest of the page falls in line.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using font-size:10vw instead. i'll just use a fallback to correct for lack of browser support :)